# Occasional stuck at boot-up line "Waiting for /dev to be fully populated"

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, usb

On Linux Kernel 3 boot-up occasionally gets stuck at line:

```
Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...
```

Prior to that line I can see USB device enumeration errors:

```
usb 2-1.2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-1.2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-1.2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-1.2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-1.2.3: device not accepting address 12, error -32
```

It looks like one of my USB devices cannot be enumerated and so the kernel cannot finish population of `/dev` and just hangs there (until my watchdog kicks in). I wonder if we can tell the kernel to not hang when a USB device cannot be enumerated. Since I can reset the faulty USB device later, this would be an acceptable workaround for me.

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/init.d/udev` I changed line

```
if udevadm settle; then
```

to

```
if udevadm settle --timeout=10; then
```

This will stop waiting for `/dev` to be fully populated after 10 seconds. The default timeout was 180 seconds.